# How can I create several variables upon one condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

Suppose I have the following variables (the exact data generator process is not relevant right now): `C_n`, `L_n`, `U_n`, `C_c`, `L_c`, `U_c`, `C_s`, `L_s`, `U_s` all these variables are numeric.

(Note that `U_c` is built using `L_c` and `C_c`, same for `U_n`, and `U_s`)

So I make these operations:

```
data <- data %>% 
  # Build U with the highest value between U_n, U_c, U_s
    mutate(U12 = ifelse(U_c >= U_s, U_c, U_s)) %>%
    mutate(U = ifelse(U12 >= U_n, U12, U_n))
  # get L and C with the associated U
    mutate(L = case_when(
               U == U_c ~ L_c,
               U == U_s ~ L_s,
               U == U_n ~ L_n
             ),
           C = case_when(
               U == U_c ~ C_c,
               U == U_s ~ C_s,
               U == U_n ~ C_n
             ),
           regime = case_when(
               U == U_c ~ "Complex",
               U == U_s ~ "Simple",
               U == U_n ~ "Notch"
             ))
```

In my real problem, I have way more variables to create than these three.  So I'd like to not use the `case_when` function so often.

So my question is: Is there a way to produce `L`, and `C` with just one `case_when`? Or a more clever way?

So in words: I want to pick the highest U (between `U_c`, `U_s`, and `U_n`) and then pick up the associated L and C. (e.g. If `U_c` is the highest in that row, then `L = L_c`, and `C = C_c`).

I suppose each conditional (`case_when`) takes its own time to process and I need to speed things up.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Data

```
structure(list(U_c = c(11.7855657153651, 11.5225483722288, 11.8795146373457, 
12.2724152444076, 11.4463320274637, 11.5061132446192, 11.8733232888343, 
12.757310053628, 12.0800228234474, 11.7221377886028, 11.5346238289216, 
11.9979554513778, 12.1013018377494, 11.7748215824691, 11.9680743443141, 
11.7318594410147, 12.4271264123935, 12.178923405588, 11.9300158418339, 
11.2132544746492, 12.0874948669781, 12.0502574032969, 12.1015284791768, 
11.658091073654, 11.8024734541939, 11.2761336533498, 11.5826088803584, 
11.6940990378542, 12.1741261993965, 11.488017577077, 11.8546503370412, 
12.4185309083321, 11.4630737822674, 12.063111572583, 11.6794175784536, 
11.7181272376379, 12.0439531637464, 11.6855604427439, 11.5300734186255, 
11.0704958463238, 12.3528012560341, 12.2051551454967, 11.8181627419022, 
11.7458117070543, 11.6879564578503, 12.2551914323627, 11.810731268587, 
11.6389152044322, 11.9342904453467, 11.7958257295596, 11.8334600799018, 
11.8510892050884, 11.3148572732714, 11.579997540212, 12.0805146313661, 
11.5507452170695, 11.7835878865745, 11.9133930484228, 11.3932185856492, 
11.5632620795432, 12.0967513578827, 11.6437127269257, 11.9750417440628, 
11.3116770811748, 12.1539699164135, 11.7611776133809, 12.4731020005405, 
13.2827605519458, 11.4758316315569, 11.5546761708014, 11.6421140094228, 
11.8484040554847, 12.0815678643518, 11.4118623360241, 12.3057977939571, 
11.5115143317822, 12.3815260137654, 11.7419963720044, 12.4647641423482, 
11.6828464301411, 11.8729011897202, 12.058489541665, 11.15295386482, 
12.1094871620535, 11.9611899857961, 11.7513205607925, 11.207533407721, 
11.3250346813526, 11.3943069492929, 12.2704081118631, 12.3691969938648, 
12.2230161236057, 10.8694025279785, 11.9053139223967, 11.9656775271833, 
12.3914263947455, 11.5588296255977, 12.9830891625009, 11.6131264809166, 
12.2073990679311, 11.6763401116541, 11.4144486001447, 12.570829973071, 
11.9937143999235, 12.5666732613703, 12.5781052903918, 11.1266173295312, 
11.7583945477886, 12.0118236965224, 11.5448156885708, 11.3732044215226, 
11.6405758018192, 11.7770622862986, 11.8454551212603, 12.2474917624257, 
12.0236474961022, 11.7281897287259, 11.935142751417), U_s = c(12.246601245638, 
11.9127846112164, 12.0726597448225, 12.3332389844315, 11.8914523497187, 
11.9288425565222, 12.5110639583434, 11.9237843274473, 12.3240628505494, 
12.1802697754407, 11.5980321715924, 12.4620301392392, 12.4234208779688, 
12.0894327630409, 12.241374612599, 12.3507671308325, 11.8551404760762, 
11.9734100257492, 12.2527474350073, 11.4170342497655, 12.1987862991744, 
12.0491967886119, 12.4016356193626, 12.0872429483554, 12.3314160612017, 
11.8148770794048, 11.9314969846124, 12.1460501920199, 12.7026439366469, 
11.996048772962, 12.4807468846589, 12.6898345260893, 11.7603343906523, 
12.4670394121478, 11.8565036244344, 12.2742029012264, 12.4387232167143, 
11.8986832286417, 11.9888766049223, 11.5024184159827, 12.1900130189018, 
12.2836561157148, 12.3873457397229, 12.1110746363066, 11.962380611033, 
12.7202591216652, 12.1106538115441, 12.1602504413224, 12.4278014442536, 
12.3228976721316, 12.2269030001061, 12.1848459019562, 11.8845827906952, 
11.947736022797, 12.0389326305121, 11.9540629479584, 11.93838986074, 
12.5292927405268, 11.9458641360854, 12.1932835785957, 12.2919616861543, 
11.9334439804038, 12.392904892643, 11.8353356222722, 12.2567421388715, 
12.3023095628234, 12.2308933142754, 12.441065434084, 11.9001820354513, 
12.159230501322, 12.2097584079989, 12.1432155023927, 12.3868471302984, 
11.9860802183931, 12.389279465569, 12.1115296118156, 12.5512824812018, 
12.2133115323019, 12.2586148480265, 12.1030998390632, 12.4600403472909, 
12.5479334624478, 11.5293970528766, 12.4548801449925, 12.454766181058, 
12.2586468593155, 11.8342111691822, 11.6896419573254, 11.7211124522787, 
12.7454979112792, 12.3494095525294, 12.4564708694723, 11.4438384428285, 
12.294612097716, 12.5682287351646, 12.6347766670296, 12.02264115637, 
12.6378017563218, 12.176927128853, 12.5500161192258, 12.0962202680087, 
11.7812563449058, 12.5043092108525, 12.445828989842, 12.6996889204895, 
12.6887268778122, 11.4779257754662, 12.3891636281069, 12.0628536895872, 
12.2587883479983, 11.758872105598, 12.2547635676201, 12.1049008950697, 
12.1278687427532, 12.3872380264167, 11.8258717692514, 12.2231083394746, 
12.4160134764918), U_n = c(12.0411374476332, 11.9127846647778, 
12.0726598153403, 12.3332390742845, 11.8914524026975, 11.7613482097467, 
12.2748709378404, 11.9237844660244, 12.1117148265487, 11.9819234450358, 
11.4757852320822, 12.2316084133847, 12.4234209608336, 11.9038431763829, 
12.2413746820183, 12.1319433363536, 11.701346002765, 11.8040275761997, 
12.0464127117266, 11.3184787677371, 12.0015662451201, 12.0491968736429, 
12.1797991613247, 11.9003935024915, 12.1161479145242, 11.660944811741, 
11.7653726013682, 11.9530523002019, 12.4458946302795, 11.8193862295565, 
12.247865769669, 12.4374950902827, 11.6164050893059, 12.2370023477985, 
11.8565036924449, 12.0653674430946, 12.2113456630733, 11.8986832991899, 
11.8149090270136, 11.388953784671, 12.1900131269931, 12.2836562006068, 
12.1650361857855, 11.9220568114417, 11.9623806827479, 12.4629147568998, 
11.9227262169665, 11.9641757445355, 12.2016935277223, 12.1075999300864, 
12.0235361521943, 11.9877992820488, 11.7206827279259, 11.94773606953, 
12.0389327120631, 11.7838362958421, 11.9383899238017, 12.2909649850566, 
11.7754995377899, 11.9936755908268, 12.2919617540298, 11.933444049466, 
12.1710995671098, 11.6773465659245, 12.0529165618181, 12.0910928318343, 
12.2308934183867, 12.2182464669845, 11.7372909654523, 11.9631158034366, 
12.0072308890193, 12.1432155643045, 12.386847207668, 11.8104201042441, 
12.1701225700252, 11.9206383784445, 12.3138697729029, 12.0129625648839, 
12.2586149581386, 11.9149327769422, 12.2296901013359, 12.3079972465059, 
11.41429470732, 12.2277856526362, 12.2250595420114, 12.0516295264919, 
11.6771379218092, 11.6896419968189, 11.580319393322, 12.4857652880321, 
12.135376562085, 12.2284906266636, 11.4438384699319, 12.0841250161574, 
12.3270411301931, 12.3878449235689, 11.8451302138231, 12.393120973129, 
11.9788656079433, 12.3125911552615, 11.9098068923458, 11.6316290395159, 
12.273461003663, 12.2187280206357, 12.4472184389355, 12.4374723327458, 
11.3689992232031, 12.1662589964825, 11.8820850193444, 12.0503441808423, 
11.7588721493488, 12.0469363780724, 11.9168298790492, 11.9386011423455, 
12.387238110486, 11.8258718523797, 12.0199106084888, 12.1906289836004
), L_c = c(8.00000012786231, 8.00000023989623, 8.00000012810319, 
8.00000024382699, 8.00000014375621, 8.00000020153595, 8.00000021342878, 
8.00000015129041, 8.00000013432837, 8.00000014080798, 8.00000015178547, 
8.00000017694761, 8.00000012720178, 8.00000021977522, 8.00000023355215, 
8.00000018466456, 8.00000013121537, 8.00000017807328, 8.00000022262448, 
8.00000023698598, 8.0000002130428, 8.00000019060294, 8.00000017345066, 
8.00000014192226, 8.00000022135405, 8.00000024102761, 8.00000013880459, 
8.00000012975634, 8.00000022637215, 8.0000001267042, 8.00000021926072, 
8.00000013385126, 8.00000021979882, 8.00000015399238, 8.00000024268751, 
8.00000021350717, 8.00000019139905, 8.00000015526457, 8.00000017595037, 
8.00000014873222, 8.00000015419383, 8.00000022679462, 8.00000024405916, 
8.00000023851965, 8.00000023470426, 8.00000024742317, 8.00000023542674, 
8.00000012725377, 8.00000020616829, 8.00000014265489, 8.00000022359299, 
8.000000192876, 8.00000018658916, 8.00000021174072, 8.00000016734146, 
8.00000024054552, 8.00000023288822, 8.00000017533791, 8.00000018577319, 
8.00000020381044, 8.00000021380145, 8.00000020073864, 8.00000016062443, 
8.00000014560034, 8.0000002196303, 8.00000022547372, 8.00000013506547, 
8.00000012933315, 8.00000020809666, 8.00000021151738, 8.00000020103055, 
8.0000001597244, 8.00000020535759, 8.00000020321577, 8.00000019308594, 
8.00000020659586, 8.0000001451491, 8.00000019209758, 8.00000014466789, 
8.0000002277255, 8.00000024055548, 8.00000023186535, 8.00000024340387, 
8.00000024528717, 8.00000014279103, 8.00000022115289, 8.00000020892546, 
8.00000023845915, 8.00000017133892, 8.00000017280214, 8.00000024759175, 
8.00000016346987, 8.000000228181, 8.00000020779673, 8.00000012591269, 
8.00000021254574, 8.0000002304499, 8.00000022057199, 8.00000023869859, 
8.00000012888798, 8.00000021790439, 8.00000013242699, 8.00000016203032, 
8.00000024725563, 8.00000022987974, 8.00000023491871, 8.00000018072891, 
8.00000023925182, 8.00000012421822, 8.00000014347815, 8.00000017992456, 
8.00000017905061, 8.00000014188572, 8.00000018145906, 8.00000023836449, 
8.00000016680221, 8.00000016507824, 8.00000016307371), C_c = c(336.84210183527, 
310.071460328294, 346.840469852791, 391.259899805406, 302.641026549921, 
308.45696760453, 346.174345587748, 452.233682486957, 368.973901278721, 
330.22327561487, 311.261986684273, 359.782203938224, 371.387591115703, 
335.713528716311, 356.481331373633, 331.230939410621, 409.951155595414, 
380.299555819924, 352.312254392162, 280.797324367776, 369.820024962901, 
365.618665218894, 371.413366910975, 323.645864497058, 338.624249771287, 
286.561783015619, 316.029053262789, 327.33074612816, 379.74386257933, 
306.687138962198, 344.171527566894, 408.894316810334, 304.260862386431, 
367.064613146951, 325.824285645133, 329.808291117563, 364.911177373401, 
326.453926947041, 310.812930491621, 268.053907833012, 400.884542308293, 
383.349673260231, 340.284707521394, 332.681409674061, 326.699781165537, 
389.221943749282, 339.497396083093, 321.697085619392, 352.7785570198, 
337.922653661391, 341.909949132724, 343.790623481237, 290.15861503762, 
315.768136641415, 369.029545214441, 312.857100573788, 336.634121242342, 
350.503612648177, 297.547680283785, 314.100072706753, 370.870368921844, 
322.183758647678, 357.248823465556, 289.861869688867, 377.416116607022, 
334.284716381397, 415.641137032941, 526.653764570527, 305.499888955187, 
313.247034655649, 322.021515206803, 343.503638892488, 369.148732313952, 
299.327660847884, 395.234094890908, 308.986795760698, 404.369332907946, 
332.284265715725, 414.60457412317, 326.175621704841, 346.12896940612, 
366.544161353635, 275.356761424901, 372.319413511236, 355.724283049814, 
333.255504533023, 280.277484564103, 291.10990809616, 297.651356676842, 
391.0219735038, 402.87066163417, 385.437649075101, 250.892319018369, 
349.627250473406, 356.217615955797, 405.576013175764, 313.659462175427, 
483.102527188997, 319.09107767416, 383.611493240882, 325.509212027252, 
299.57525145239, 427.945996853833, 359.312225064077, 427.416764685416, 
428.873550967919, 273.00719440637, 333.993868777513, 361.322469865633, 
312.269651201221, 295.646296551447, 321.865474256131, 335.948644271039, 
343.188682184043, 388.313654469751, 362.639832858316, 330.850279651014, 
352.871591391293), C_s = c(386.529065516832, 349.82170282716, 
365.736844498251, 394.929509649054, 347.066950849498, 350.251297771875, 
419.98534711739, 345.461011112488, 393.682743565952, 379.328093115438, 
313.135949576663, 413.393375533493, 407.746289100963, 366.897332284658, 
386.023142687125, 400.586905944709, 338.366950773479, 351.936552184747, 
387.423687015172, 295.952757467808, 378.206365521739, 361.500081446696, 
403.858242608742, 368.098609282603, 396.774699652824, 338.483491576921, 
349.035871290179, 374.043446045045, 444.724099528268, 358.545427995733, 
416.184257117332, 439.245308229058, 330.168365258868, 412.959303810491, 
341.181854601568, 390.009111511018, 409.975841573696, 345.352790533448, 
356.078150078492, 306.600183209122, 376.419877757133, 389.222920664279, 
404.375409183781, 370.179507404071, 352.660031352, 445.470841937836, 
369.131144252346, 377.070476297843, 408.562435982261, 396.806212431557, 
384.387190226467, 378.034033092146, 347.075420854873, 354.031302556954, 
360.558771624822, 352.693794650002, 351.044524640639, 422.461734691028, 
352.817762673618, 380.590378046399, 393.201511091201, 349.858821485015, 
403.824225657045, 341.942637180078, 384.854313882765, 392.494159367188, 
381.355508220131, 404.933471978472, 346.191415054528, 377.110057104211, 
383.534673332024, 375.695086295476, 404.07929463986, 357.624796315708, 
400.946764331264, 371.991032748566, 421.397729097153, 381.334557994948, 
384.477558199094, 369.361038902472, 413.312661113591, 424.341427250581, 
307.803769154816, 409.660146843812, 412.586929092406, 388.12696626862, 
341.15727177476, 326.784251262162, 327.622451092949, 448.485855341407, 
395.462663620928, 410.649244635059, 301.139026292499, 391.730309109113, 
425.812115712584, 432.657051204395, 359.327290099976, 429.956231749434, 
379.043961779025, 421.411948560299, 367.682171776834, 334.868019251891, 
413.875477825345, 409.667348067137, 439.406756243356, 437.912189814386, 
303.300807855758, 405.027295998748, 362.352521767551, 389.602926169399, 
333.859421333375, 388.963712403007, 369.268810997484, 370.420313526609, 
402.584588333268, 336.259409980998, 384.215194447966, 407.760206697701
), C_n = c(362.998169925077, 349.821709939134, 365.736853384224, 
394.929521209611, 347.066957748941, 332.448468067701, 391.171881927813, 
345.461026293288, 369.02232139645, 356.934193271586, 301.193439393373, 
385.620747290515, 407.746300490925, 346.466183865305, 386.023152034656, 
374.836351624302, 322.44060413155, 333.867634746991, 363.751534481165, 
286.723380178881, 355.98958244652, 361.500091568176, 377.591163476362, 
347.477785362407, 371.626071963078, 322.538737211042, 331.424951721667, 
352.48396342819, 412.004516575503, 339.432999315238, 387.970963023829, 
407.390799532589, 315.536525621482, 385.255214443433, 341.181862566183, 
365.928734566139, 382.742823908927, 345.352798788458, 337.355293140119, 
295.689632328276, 376.419890700789, 389.22293153849, 378.026670009202, 
349.230120211949, 352.660039948699, 412.633352852233, 348.347288090379, 
355.03304118152, 381.55258767259, 371.652608989646, 361.194484318843, 
355.844458405643, 329.774045043067, 354.031309088328, 360.558781372686, 
334.505307903393, 351.044532458792, 393.257260562536, 334.609702222221, 
357.997169439312, 393.20152067558, 349.858829804143, 377.562516137105, 
325.451700200803, 361.587854512605, 368.021407249467, 381.355520868773, 
378.496627817389, 329.029621249674, 355.06637180587, 360.476575931748, 
375.695094824184, 404.079305459661, 338.657729889037, 375.13939287169, 
350.755614633191, 392.361259154242, 358.623847615525, 384.477571615759, 
348.540882723884, 385.552777202699, 394.840159528811, 296.70317978829, 
382.476977925778, 384.941634465438, 364.343770308709, 324.790339957132, 
326.784256673658, 313.392597585046, 415.17231242818, 370.521204683781, 
383.309901458906, 301.13902989233, 367.378165764714, 396.078634682405, 
401.842792541647, 340.09141077715, 399.568425556148, 356.694923268465, 
392.373232803246, 347.127100802334, 319.494127575608, 386.02673347839, 
382.48304033171, 407.526758086109, 406.268175139553, 292.911211956163, 
378.575626841142, 342.638976588119, 365.586683103063, 333.859427259516, 
365.04839776757, 348.463217883679, 349.432905911696, 402.584599595866, 
336.25941916795, 361.049645644496, 380.877025468168), L_s = c(9.22764371934814, 
8.44632845013745, 9.98826646824553, 11.1092942204224, 8.80657252026952, 
9.58834635997006, 8.24541329612796, 17.196537550275, 11.2964651971963, 
8.79769731255068, 13.6939881310589, 8.56024252463774, 9.22442638604674, 
10.8025850139758, 9.13759878383663, 8.03202324319749, 16.5263265364257, 
14.2363907907871, 9.08437175240781, 12.8897903600072, 12.3957651076127, 
12.01408109124, 10.3456587670093, 9.29612759349619, 9.07818373213025, 
9.17401062410078, 11.3535461821847, 10.0012953137067, 8.16087268922835, 
8.75524001077555, 8.2521191619317, 11.2903811187681, 12.5351636430203, 
9.35491931838109, 11.094763593176, 9.03996275337215, 8.94999407316628, 
11.5634445529916, 10.3653594993756, 9.32929787996101, 13.7436805185527, 
10.892096699328, 8.45407357952313, 9.87982213489027, 10.992960811397, 
9.20516239287354, 11.0021739377006, 8.75689439735354, 9.00421620852391, 
8.30681816504765, 9.08908921605462, 10.4987536856276, 8.22084657463554, 
8.15047490671777, 11.717449579397, 9.89578844007889, 9.83543974764119, 
8.13154985854771, 8.93305828607546, 8.99273148558906, 8.24584181321053, 
10.5607206702844, 9.38722303237964, 8.1184889996053, 12.5316865729279, 
9.77700459775375, 13.3490002693602, 16.4634879882574, 10.6536595437715, 
8.63674313101384, 8.23115718361218, 8.32644556066341, 8.61820002024971, 
8.61175240024843, 12.0457442738735, 8.38437317434956, 11.4344516563491, 
10.4926187804665, 13.5471293935644, 9.79475128728148, 8.44755498484564, 
8.43138701604472, 11.1038985689361, 11.1279145566536, 8.496694270285, 
9.07720388784218, 8.62894054093072, 8.06473006748364, 10.3290157480425, 
9.44653877404173, 13.1086218174603, 10.2669981791936, 9.11143675889817, 
9.63768875230176, 9.21814742471304, 10.7103944715238, 10.9387090456377, 
15.3638599244535, 8.71856805882473, 11.2270891717979, 10.7787281325283, 
9.24987758692433, 13.9053725173523, 9.94867211629894, 12.7431656002559, 
12.847135817901, 10.403020064607, 8.17002558917153, 13.1251864859427, 
8.02775295378381, 8.13356433440425, 8.13318049360117, 10.0968893159362, 
11.8974778838158, 9.87859928311565, 14.0038320571143, 8.87075924040782, 
8.53443014971094), L_n = c(9.22764271934814, 8.44632745013745, 
9.98826546824553, 11.1092932204224, 8.80657152026952, 9.58834535997006, 
8.24541229612796, 17.196536550275, 11.2964641971963, 8.79769631255068, 
13.6939871310589, 8.56024152463774, 9.22442538604674, 10.8025840139758, 
9.13759778383663, 8.03202224319749, 16.5263255364257, 14.2363897907871, 
9.08437075240781, 12.8897893600072, 12.3957641076127, 12.01408009124, 
10.3456577670093, 9.29612659349619, 9.07818273213025, 9.17400962410078, 
11.3535451821847, 10.0012943137067, 8.16087168922835, 8.75523901077555, 
8.2521181619317, 11.2903801187681, 12.5351626430203, 9.35491831838109, 
11.094762593176, 9.03996175337215, 8.94999307316628, 11.5634435529916, 
10.3653584993756, 9.32929687996101, 13.7436795185527, 10.892095699328, 
8.45407257952313, 9.87982113489027, 10.992959811397, 9.20516139287355, 
11.0021729377006, 8.75689339735354, 9.00421520852391, 8.30681716504765, 
9.08908821605462, 10.4987526856276, 8.22084557463554, 8.15047390671777, 
11.717448579397, 9.89578744007889, 9.83543874764119, 8.13154885854771, 
8.93305728607546, 8.99273048558907, 8.24584081321053, 10.5607196702844, 
9.38722203237964, 8.1184879996053, 12.5316855729279, 9.77700359775375, 
13.3489992693602, 16.4634869882574, 10.6536585437715, 8.63674213101384, 
8.23115618361218, 8.32644456066341, 8.61819902024971, 8.61175140024843, 
12.0457432738735, 8.38437217434956, 11.4344506563491, 10.4926177804665, 
13.5471283935644, 9.79475028728148, 8.44755398484564, 8.43138601604472, 
11.1038975689361, 11.1279135566537, 8.49669327028501, 9.07720288784218, 
8.62893954093072, 8.06472906748364, 10.3290147480425, 9.44653777404173, 
13.1086208174603, 10.2669971791936, 9.11143575889817, 9.63768775230176, 
9.21814642471304, 10.7103934715238, 10.9387080456377, 15.3638589244535, 
8.71856705882473, 11.2270881717979, 10.7787271325283, 9.24987658692433, 
13.9053715173523, 9.94867111629894, 12.7431646002559, 12.847134817901, 
10.403019064607, 8.17002458917153, 13.1251854859427, 8.02775195378381, 
8.13356333440425, 8.13317949360117, 10.0968883159362, 11.8974768838158, 
9.87859828311565, 14.0038310571143, 8.87075824040782, 8.53442914971094
)), row.names = c(NA, -118L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Could you provide some small sample data and the desired outcome of those data?

Comment: Also, could you describe (in words) the logic behind the code you provided?

Comment: Done, both @jpsmith

Comment: Before your edit I thought the question was about duplicating code - hence my answer. But now I think it's about the time it takes the code to run. Could you clarify?

Comment: @SamR sorry for the confusion. It was both, I don't want to use a lot of `case_when` statements. But I want to make it fast (if possible). Imma try your answer in a bit.

Comment: @JorgeParedes my method will prevent code duplication but it won't make it faster. It can be made faster though. The best way depends. How large is your real data, and how many new columns in this pattern are you creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the conditions as a character vector:

```r
build_condition <- function(var) {
    case_when_conditions <- list(
        `U == U_c` = sprintf("%s_c", var),
        `U == U_s` = sprintf("%s_s", var),
        `U == U_n` = sprintf("%s_n", var)
    )

    Map(
        \(x, y) sprintf("%s ~ %s", x, y),
        names(case_when_conditions), case_when_conditions
    ) |>
        unlist() |>
        paste(collapse = ", ") |>
        paste0("case_when(", ... = _, ")")
}
```

We can then apply this to whichever columns we like to create the conditions:

```r
vars <- c("L", "C")
conds <- vapply(vars, build_condition, character(1))
```

This produces a named vector of conditions of the form:

```r
conds[1]
#                                                           L 
# "case_when(U == U_c ~ L_c, U == U_s ~ L_s, U == U_n ~ L_n)"
```

We can use these inside `mutate()` with [`rlang::parse_exprs()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/parse_expr.html) and the [splice operator](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html):

```r
library(rlang)

dat |>
    mutate(!!!parse_exprs(conds))

# # A tibble: 118 × 13
#      U_c   U_s   U_n   L_c   C_c   C_s   C_n   L_s   L_n   U12     U     L     C
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  11.8  12.2  12.0  8.00  337.  387.  363.  9.23  9.23  12.2  12.2  9.23  387.
#  2  11.5  11.9  11.9  8.00  310.  350.  350.  8.45  8.45  11.9  11.9  8.45  350.
#  3  11.9  12.1  12.1  8.00  347.  366.  366.  9.99  9.99  12.1  12.1  9.99  366.
#  4  12.3  12.3  12.3  8.00  391.  395.  395. 11.1  11.1   12.3  12.3 11.1   395.
#  5  11.4  11.9  11.9  8.00  303.  347.  347.  8.81  8.81  11.9  11.9  8.81  347.
#  6  11.5  11.9  11.8  8.00  308.  350.  332.  9.59  9.59  11.9  11.9  9.59  350.
#  7  11.9  12.5  12.3  8.00  346.  420.  391.  8.25  8.25  12.5  12.5  8.25  420.
#  8  12.8  11.9  11.9  8.00  452.  345.  345. 17.2  17.2   12.8  12.8  8.00  452.
#  9  12.1  12.3  12.1  8.00  369.  394.  369. 11.3  11.3   12.3  12.3 11.3   394.
# 10  11.7  12.2  12.0  8.00  330.  379.  357.  8.80  8.80  12.2  12.2  8.80  379.
# # ℹ 108 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

*Note: The* `build_condition()` *function requires at least R 4.2 because of the [native pipe placeholder](https://davidbudzynski.github.io/general/2022/04/23/r-native-placeholder.html). However, you can switch to the* `magrittr` `%>%` *pipe (replacing `_` with `.`) or rewrite it as a nested set of function calls without pipes.*